Visual Studio Code gives error EISDIR illegal operation on a directory, read
For some reason it can't even open solution it used to open. Even if i try to create and open a solution it just give me the same EISDIR error after creating a solution. I'm using vscode-solution-explorer extension to create my solutions.
I tried searching for an answer but couldn't find one.

https://github.com/fernandoescolar/vscode-solution-explorer/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+EISDIR I don't see any issue tickets. consider raising one. if you do, please add a link to it here.
